# How can I avoid duplicate content when using a reverse proxy in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx's reverse proxy to route from blog.example.com to example.com/blog.

both paths display the same content.

```
For example:
blog.example.com/aaa
example.com/blog/aaa
```

I have a question about using Robots.txt settings and redirects to prevent this duplicate content.

When I try to apply a 301 redirect from blog.example.com to example.com/blog, I encounter a redirect loop.

Here's the code I used:

```
   location /{
            return 301 https://$server_name/blog$request_uri;
        }
```

To solve this issue, I applied location /blog/robots.txt { return 404; } using the map.

This way, the bot will index as example.com/blog/aaa even though it can access blog.example.com/aaa?

Or should I apply User-agent: * Disallow: / should be applied to blog.example.com's robots.txt?

```
map $upstream_http_location $_upstream_http_location_prefix { # 1
  default $upstream_http_location; # 2
  "~^/"                 "/blog";   # 3
  "~*^http"             "";        # 4
  "~*^((?!http|\/).)*"  "/blog/";  # 5
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    return       301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;  
         add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }
        
        
    location /blog/wp-admin { return 301 /blog/404; }
    location /blog/wp-login.php { return 301 /blog/404; }

    # Prevent the blog's robots.txt from being proxied
    location /blog/robots.txt { return 404; }

 location /blog {
    rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1  break;
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";

    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_last_modified on;
    sub_filter_types text/html text/css text/xml text/javascript application/json;
    sub_filter 'blog.example.com' 'example.com/blog';

    sub_filter 'src="/wp-content/' 'src="/blog/wp-content/';
    
    proxy_hide_header Location;
    add_header Location "$_upstream_http_location_prefix$upstream_http_location";

    sub_filter 'http:' 'https:';

        proxy_pass https://blog.example.com;
   }


}
```